# Moment.js returning "December 31, 1969"

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, momentjs

Essentially I am recreating one of FCC's backend project : https://timestamp-ms.herokuapp.com/

It looks like with my current code, if I type the following: 
http://localhost:3000/1

It returns as so:

```js
{"unix":"1","natural":"December 31, 1969"}
```

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path')
var app = express();
var moment = require('moment')
var port = 3000;
//homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var fileName = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');
  res.sendFile(fileName, function (err) {
    if (err) {console.error(err)}
    console.log('This is the homepage')
  });
});

//input of the page
app.get('/:dataString', function(req, res) {
  var dataString = req.params.dataString;
  var output;
  //Using regex, checks if the dataString has only number characters
  if(/^[0-9]*$/.test(dataString)){
    output = moment(dataString, "X")
  } else{
    output = moment(dataString, "MMMM D, YYYY")
  }

  if (output.isValid()){
    res.json({
      unix: output.format("X"),
      natural: output.format("MMMM D, YYYY")
    });
  } else{
    res.json({
      unix: 'null',
      natural: 'null'
    });
  }
})

app.listen(port,function(){
  console.log("turn on. Port is: ", port)
})
```

I would have expected returning January 1 1970, but I am not sure where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be "January 1 1970" in the GMT timezone. Moment most likely formats the date in your own timezone which then becomes "December 31, 1969" if you are West of GMT.

To format the date in the UTC timezone you can write:

```
moment('1', 'X').utc().format('MMMM D, YYYY')
```

This will output "January 1, 1970".

Comment: From the Moment.js Docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

"By default, moment parses and displays in local time."

Answer (score 1):

It's January 1 1970 UTC, but if you are in a different timezone that has a negative offset from UTC (such as all of North America and South America), then moment.js can report December 31, 1969. The few hours earlier makes the time earlier than midnight, and thus a day earlier.

To get a moment object that will assume UTC rather than the timezone of the machine it is running on, you can use `moment.utc()`:

```
var output = moment.utc('1', 'X');
console.log(output.format('MMMM D, YYYY')); // 'January 1, 1970'
```